# Resolving a constructor with two arguments of the same interface?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

Another developer and had this conversation today:

**Me:** Dependency Injection is cool, lol.

**Dennis**: What happens when I need an instance of the DoStuff class and the only constructor I have is DoStuff( ISomeInterface interface1, ISomeInterface interface2 ) where the concrete types are completely different?

**Me:** ...

We use Unity as our preferred container. How would I register that when I need to resolve ISomeInterface that the concrete type can be two different types?

Comment: While this situation can be resolved, you may want to reconsider such a constructor and refactor it to something less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ParameterOverride class. It allows you to specify parameters by name:

```
   container.Resolve<IDoStuff>(new ParameterOverrides<DoStuff> { { "interface1", new SomeInterfaceImpl() }, { "interface2", AnotherSomeInterfaceImpl() } });
```